# Angular JS ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently trying to build a angular js menu here is my code I can't seem to get the pages to load at all. Am I missing something? have I included all the correct scripts required. Very new to angular.

```js
// create the module and name it scotchApp    
var scotchApp = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);  
  
// configure our routes    
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider  
  
    // route for the home page    
        .when('/', {  
        templateUrl: 'http://www.habboholiday.net/pages/home.html',  
        controller: 'mainController'  
    })  
  
    // route for the about page    
    .when('/about', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',  
        controller: 'aboutController'  
    })  
  
    // route for the contact page    
    .when('/contact', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',  
        controller: 'contactController'  
    });  
  
});  
  
// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope    
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {  
    // create a message to display in our view    
    $scope.HomeMessage = 'Home Controller Called !!!';  
});  
  
scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.AboutMessage = 'About Controller Called !!!';  
});  
  
scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.ContactMessage = 'Contact Controller Called !!!';  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<!-- define angular app -->    
<html ng-app="RoutingApp">    
<head>    
    <!-- SPELLS -->    
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</head>    
    
<body ng-controller="mainController">    
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">    
        <div class="container">    
            <div class="navbar-header">    
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">    
                    Angular Routing Example    
                </a>    
            </div>    
    
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Contact</a></li>    
            </ul>    
        </div>    
    </nav>    
    
    <div id="main">    
        <!-- angular templating : This is where content will be injected -->    
        <div ng-view></div>    
    </div>    
</body>    
    
</html>
```

Comment: In your snippet everything appears to be correctly running. I suggest that you call the scope in the different views. Have you tried place `<pre>{{HomeMessage}}</pre>` in the home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ng-app to your html element

```
<html ng-app="RoutingApp">
  ....
</html>
```

In addition, you can move your Angular script references to the bottom of your body or they should at least be contained within `<head>` tags

Comment: Your code snippet works now though? Well, you're getting page load errors but that's regarding cross domain loading and about.html and contact.html are not defined in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed `ng-app` directive. Add that to your HTML and try.

Comment: <html ng-app="RoutingApp">..</html> 
This will ensure that Browser understands the angular code present within this HTML block.